# Flutter: GroupedListView not working as it should

Tags: flutter, dart, grouped-list

Why are my **first date and first 2 items correctly built** but not the rest? The first `date header` wrap my text correctly but the padding is incorrect and the rest has the correct padding but does not wrap my text. [This is how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG7xS.jpg).

```js
GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    elements: activityList,
                    groupBy: (element) => element['date'].substring(0, 10),
                    groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => 
                      child: Container(
                          height: 35,
                          width: 125,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                            color: themeProvider.isDarkMode
                                ? Color(0xFF64B6F7)
                                : Color(0xFFFFCC00),
                          ),
                          child: Center(child: Text(...))
                    ),
                    itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
                        item1['date'].compareTo(item2['date']),
                    itemBuilder: (context, element) { 
                      return Card(
                        elevation: 5,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                      child: ListTile(
                        //listtile
                      ),
                    );},
                    useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                    floatingHeader: true,
                  )
```

The problem is caused by `useStickyGroupSeparators` but I would want to use that.

Comment: Can you try wrapping `Container` in your `groupSeparatorBuilder` with a `Row` =>`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` and leave the rest as it is? Seems that does the trick.

Comment: @cobster still doesnt work the first `ListTile` still has margin from the date which I don't know why as the rest work just fine. And the date(except for the first one) doesn't look the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I tried to reproduce the effect. Is this what you want to achieve?

[image: Screenshot]

The code:

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          elements: items,
          groupBy: (element) => element['date'].substring(0, 10),
          groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                  height: 35,
                  width: 125,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    color: const Color(0xFFFFCC00),
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text(groupByValue))),
            ],
          ),
          itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
              item1['date'].compareTo(item2['date']),
          itemBuilder: (context, element) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 5,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(element['activity']),
              ),
            );
          },
          useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
          floatingHeader: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Mock data:

```
final items = [
  {"date": "2022-07-08", "activity": "Activity 1"},
  {"date": "2022-07-08", "activity": "Activity 2"},
  {"date": "2022-07-09", "activity": "Activity 3"},
  {"date": "2022-07-09", "activity": "Activity 4"},
  {"date": "2022-07-10", "activity": "Activity 5"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 6"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 7"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 8"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 10"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 11"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 12"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 13"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 14"},
  {"date": "2022-07-11", "activity": "Activity 15"},
  {"date": "2022-07-12", "activity": "Activity 9"},
];
```